# next js console about getServerSideProps props

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops

Can I check the value in terminal if I take console of the value received through getServerSideProps in the page component?

ex)

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async({ req, res }) => {
  const data = useHook();
   // data = 1;
  return {
    data
  }
}

const MainPage = ({ data }) => {
   console.log(data); // i expect value = 1
   return <div>test</div>
}
```

can i check in terminal console??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props that are passed from `getServerSideProps` should be like this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async({ req, res }) => {
  const data = useHook();
  return {
    props: {
        data
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const MainPage = ({ data }) => {
   console.log(data); // i expect value = 1
   return <div>test</div>
}
```

Comment: I forgot the prop.
What's the problem with the data not coming out even if I take a console after passing the prop?